# Trying to combine all my materials into one with my UV maps being seperate

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, objects, unreal-engine

So Im trying to export my materials into one texture which I could then use in Unreal engine for that object. The problem is that I only have 1 object and I have unwrapped it multiple times at different parts. I have only one UV Map in the Data Tab next to the modifiers one. Already hating UV mapping and texturing this problem has made me hate it with passion. Thanks for all the help.

[image: Pic of my blender]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when exporting my model to unity. Here is how I handled it:

- create a new UV-Map for every object. It's easier later if they all have the same name.
- select all your objects in object mode and unwrap them. With the new created UV-Map selected for every object, all objects UV-Maps now should all be in the gray square of the UV-Editor.
- Bake your textures from all the objects to a new image with the new UV-Map.

Hope this works for you :)